# Is there any document of Jhipster entire command list?

Tags: jhipster

I need to get all the commands that jhipster can execute. I am unable to find any proper documentation. Most online tutorials provide only starter commands for Jhipster.

Answer (score 3):

with command :

> jhipster -help

I was able to list out many commands that Jhipster supports.